# firebase snapshot change and angular2

Tags: firebase, angular

i'm facing a little issue with firebase and angular2. I'm loading some little task and users can apply to them.

```
loadTask() {
  let post = []
  const publicationRef = this.rootRef.child('task').child('attente');
  const usersR = this.rootRef.child('users')
return Observable.create((observer) => {
  this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance){
    publicationRef.child(key).on('value', snapshot => {
      const taskkey = snapshot.key()
      snapshot.forEach((data) => {
        const datakey = data.key();
        const dataVal = data.val();
        usersR.orderByKey().equalTo(dataVal.user).on('child_added', snapshot => {
          console.log({key: datakey,nom: snapshot.val().nom, distances: distance})
           post.push({nom: dataVal.nom, key: datakey,unom: snapshot.val().nom, uprenom: snapshot.val().prenom, distance: Math.floor(distance), uimage:snapshot.val().image, budget: dataVal.budget, description: dataVal.description, date:dataVal.date, location: dataVal.location, user: dataVal.user, id1: taskkey, id:datakey})
          observer.next(post)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
}
```

all the task are displayed but when i apply to a task , in the dom it call a new push method , so a new task with the same value appear and disseapear when i reload the page. i tried to remove the push method

```
loadTask() {
  const publicationRef = this.rootRef.child('task').child('attente');
  const usersR = this.rootRef.child('users')
return Observable.create((observer) => {
  this.geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance){
    publicationRef.child(key).on('value', snapshot => {
      const taskkey = snapshot.key()
      snapshot.forEach((data) => {
        const datakey = data.key();
        const dataVal = data.val();
        usersR.orderByKey().equalTo(dataVal.user).on('child_added', snapshot => {
          console.log({key: datakey,nom: snapshot.val().nom, distances: distance})
          const publicio = [{nom: dataVal.nom, key: datakey,unom: snapshot.val().nom, uprenom: snapshot.val().prenom, distance: Math.floor(distance), uimage:snapshot.val().image, budget: dataVal.budget, description: dataVal.description, date:dataVal.date, location: dataVal.location, user: dataVal.user, id1: taskkey, id:datakey}]
          observer.next(publicio)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
}
```

apply to a task doesnt add a new data with the same value , but in the dom it only load one set of data and not all of them

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear post in the "on" method:

```
publicationRef.child(key).on('value', snapshot => {
  post = [];
  const taskkey = snapshot.key();
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: hi adem thanks you for you anwser , i already tried , doesnt work